# How to find electric and magnetic fields if their curl and divergence are known?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we know $\nabla\cdot E$, $\nabla\times E$, $\nabla\times B$ and $\nabla\cdot B \,\,(=0)$.

Are then the electric field $E$ and magnetic field $B$ uniquely specified? If yes, how can one calculate them?

Comment: Would this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Derivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the electric field, consider the vector identity
$$
\nabla^2\vec E = \vec\nabla(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E) -  \vec\nabla\times(\vec\nabla\times \vec E)
$$
Since $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E$ and $\vec\nabla\times\vec E$ are given, the r.h.s. of this equation is fully known and equal to some function $\vec f$. So we reduce the problem to solving
$$
\nabla^2\vec E = \vec f
$$
for a given function $\vec f$, which can be done with standard methods.

For $\vec B$ the situation is analogous.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915290/find-vector-field-given-curl) it's done explicitly for a field with zero divergence, while [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem) for a generic field.